# C++ how to show exact digits of fraction part

Tags: c++, iomanip, boost-format

Is there any way in C++ (or boost lib) to show a given number digits of fraction part? But I don't want to print the trailing 0 in fraction part (eg. `1.000`, `1.500`). See this case:

```
cout << std::setprecision(3) << 5.0/7.0 << endl;    //  0.714
cout << std::setprecision(3) << 12.0/7.0 << endl;   //  1.71
cout << std::setprecision(3) << 7.0/7.0 << endl;    //  1
cout << std::setprecision(3) << 10.5/7.0 << endl;   //  1.5
```

The problem is `setprecision` prints line 1 and line 2 differently, where I want to have both lines print `0.714` and `1.714`. And still keep line 3 and line 4 `1` and `1.5`.

Comment: Using fixed precision flag std::fixed to get exact 3-digit fraction part, then convert it to double/float, and convert it back to string to get rid of trailing zero's can achieve the goal too. But isn't there a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

cout << setprecision(ceil(log10(floor(x))+3) << x;
```

Not exactly fast, but the idea is to figure out how many digits the integer part of x requires, then add the number of decimal places you're interested in to that.  You could even write your own manipulator to do that if you were really serious about it.